# EventBridge seems to have a long "warm up" time after creating a rule before it starts delivering events

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-event-bridge

I have an automated system that starts EC2 instances, and I need to know when each instance is up and running. I thought using AWS EventBridge would be the right way to do this, but it seems like there is a long delay (like 20 seconds) between when I create a rule in EventBridge and when it actually starts firing events. Here's how I thought it would work:

- Create a new rule to notify when the instance switches to the running state
- Start the instance
- When the trigger occurs, delete the rule and proceed to the next action

Here's what is actually happening:

- Create a new rule to notify when the instance switches to the running state
- Start the instance. This often switches to the 'running' state quickly, like 3-4 seconds.
- The instance reaches the 'running' state before EventBridge is ready to send events, so the trigger never occurs, and my automated process hangs.

I thought about using a single, long-lived rule, but I need to embed custom information in my Input transformer for my target, so I need a custom target for each instance that I'm launching, and the EventBridge documentation recommends that you:

*"Set a single target for each rule: While you can specify up to five targets for a given rule, managing rules is easier when you specify a single target for each rule. If more than one target needs to receive the same set of events, we recommend duplicating the rule to deliver the same events to different targets. This encapsulation simplifies maintaining rules: if the needs of the event targets diverge over time, you can update each rule and its event pattern independently of the others." (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/eventbridge/latest/userguide/eb-rules-best-practices.html)*

In addition, I could easily have more than 5 instances that are starting araound the same time as each other, which means I could exceed the five targets-per-rule limit.

I really don't want to wait 20 seconds between setting up a rule and starting my instance. My whole reason for using EventBridge was to reduce latency in the startup process caused by polling.

So my questions are:

- Is there a way to know when EventBridge rules are "warmed up" and ready to start sending events?
- What is the best way to receve a notification when an EC2 instance is running, preferably without polling, and without adding a 20 second delay to the process?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this behavior is by design and due to the distributed systems architecture (scalability with eventual consistency). IMHO this is also somewhere in the docs.

Anyways, there’s an undocumented workaround: create a new custom bus and rule and send events from the default bus there. This should fire immediately. I‘m using this pattern in CI.

Comment: So you're saying that if I have an existing Bus 'custom', at 12:00:00 created a new rule from Default to custom, and then also at 12:00:00 another rule from custom to my application, that at 12:00:01 I'd be receiving events?

Comment: Well, it’s a hack. And the custom bus must not exist yet. IIRC, EventBridge does not verify if the target bus exists when creating a rule w/ target. So, you set up a catch all rule on the default bus sending to the „to be created“ custom bus. And whenever you add new logic you create the bus/rule which should trigger much faster.

Comment: Btw: disable retries and DLQs to avoid errors due to non-existent bus.

Comment: Since the name of the non-existent custom bus needs to be set up with a rule in advance on the default bus, this trick will only work if I need a single new rule, right? If I needed to quickly set up an unknown number of new rules, would this work?

Comment: I just had a thought how to potentially simplify this: would disabling/enabling rule(s) work for you? So you set them up in advance, only change the target as needed and enable the rule(s) during your testing, disabling after you're done? I haven't tested this myself, but perhaps rule state changes take effect "immediately"?